# Java Web Start - XML parsing issue

Tags: java, xml, parsing, jnlp

I have some trouble when trying to open my application via Java Web Start. Seems to be some parsing of XML file going wrong.
But I don't think it occurs in the jnlp file, can't really understand which file that is parsed.
Looked around a bit on the net and found a lot of similar problems but solution was normally to correct the parsed XML file.

I have placed my Test.jnlp file under folder 'htdocs' on my server (where the index.html is already placed. Then I try to access it by pasting pingisranking.byethost12.com/Test.jnlp into my web browser.

Any suggestions?

```
NLParseException[ Could not parse launch file. Error at line 1.]
at com.sun.javaws.jnl.XMLFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.updateFinalLaunchDesc(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
   aused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 223; The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEntityReference(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown   Source)
at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
... 14 more
```

My jnlp file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://pingisranking.byethost12.com/"   href="htdocs/Test.jnlp">
<information>
  <title>Jnlp Testing</title>
  <vendor>BW</vendor>
  <homepage href="http://pingisranking.byethost12.com/" />
  <description>Testing Testing</description>
</information>
<security>
<all-permissions/>
</security>
<resources>
<j2se version="1.7+" />
<jar href="TestJnlp.jar" />
</resources>
<application-desc main-class="src.CreateGui" />
</jnlp>
```

Comment: It's odd, when I download the JNLP using FF it shows as a fairly standard document, but when I attempt to parse (and check) it using [JaNeLA](https://drive.google.com/drive/#folders/0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0) the server returns a mix of HTML and JS and an error *"The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference."* (probably due to that mix of HTML/JS). BTW *"I try to access it by pasting pingisranking.byethost12.com/Test.jnlp"* that's not the path as defined in the JNLP file, which is actually *"http://pingisranking.byethost12.com/htdocs/Test.jnlp"* (add `htdocs`).

Answer (score 0):

It's so mary errors can be, tt's not necessarily related to your file, some of them we can find among different resources, for example:
[JNLParseException [ Could not parse launch file. Error at line 56.]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13927265/jnlparseexception-could-not-parse-launch-file-error-at-line-56)
and
[Jnlp Could not parse launch file. Error at line 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958693/jnlp-could-not-parse-launch-file-error-at-line-0)
and https://community.oracle.com/thread/1306639

Comment: Thanks, I checked them but could not find any of them to really match my problem. Not saying they don't but.... :) Actually, I am not even sure that the jnlp is found by the launcher. But The exception information indicates that it actually does.

Comment: I removed the href pointing out the jnlp file and then the parsing problem disappeared. Instead my main class cannot be found. It is named src.CreateGui and in the Test.jar file main class is src.CreateGui in MANIFEST.MD.